# Terminal not working after some change in .bash_profile file

Tags: bash, macos, flutter

[image]

Flutter terminal not working after some change in .bash_profile file.

I have added :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

after that i did run command:

```
pbpaste > ~/.bash_profile
cat > ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: when you open the console this simply shows up? Could you eddit your question and show us the lines you added to the `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @George check question now.

Comment: Thanks, Vinit. Now it's easier for people to help you. Now this question doesn't seem to be related to Flutter, because it could happen with any update to the path. I have seen similar questions on apple exchange, superuser and also here on stackoverflow. Still, maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The pbpaste line you listed will overwrite the content of your .bash_profile with the content of your clipboard.

The line:
`cat > ~/.bash_profile`

Probably erased your ~/.bash_profile file.

To see the content of your .bash_profile run:

`cat ~/.bash_profile`

if in fact your ~/.bash_profile is empty the above cat command will give no output.

The flutter binary is not found because there is no value to the PATH environment variable.
If you don't know the location of the flutter binary either search for it in your Mac finder or reinstall it.

Once you know the full path to the flutter binary add it's location to the PATH environment variable.
If, for example, you installed flutter into the /usr/local/flutter/bin directory you should run:

`echo PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/flutter/bin >> ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate .bash_profile file in Finder.
Delete the last changes in TextEdit and save.

Restart Terminal.